# IOS swift scroll at the bottom is firing of over 50 times

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to do the classic loading more data when the user is nearing the bottom of the TableView. I have looked at some examples here and have implemented one of them however this is firing off more than 50 times instead of just once, I do not understand why this is happening this is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myTable", for: indexPath) as! HomePage

    if indexPath.row == self.Posts.count - 4 {
        LoadMore()
        print("Load More")
    }
}
```

This code is set up so that when the user gets to about the 4th last row to load more data. The LoadMore is an HTTP request which works because I use it in the ViewDid Load to get the initial data. When I look at the number of times the LoadMore fires off inside the tableView is astounding. The code works in that it first starts when the user is in the 4th last row but just never stops firing until about the 55th or 60th time. Posts is a String array and that data comes from Json but all of that is working great.

Comment: Show the complete implementation of `cellForRowAt` including the complete LoadMore, please.

Comment: call this in willdisplaycell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `willDisplayCell` method to implement `Pagination` :

```
//Call Web Service after end of Page

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            if indexPath.row == self.Posts.count - 4 {
                LoadMore()
              print("Load More")
            }
        }
```